# Override "setTemplate" Magento xml

Tags: xml, templates, magento, layout

In my theme I already use (in local.xml):

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/header/links.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Now I'm making a module where I want to change the template, hence making the module installable without any needs to modify the theme.
So almost same code from a module xml-file:

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>sociallogin/header/links.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Magento always pick the first one in local.xml
How can I override this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't (although I'll give you some possible ideas at the end of this post).  Magento is designed such that code in `local.xml` "wins" over code in an installable module file.  The basic idea is `local.xml` is where a store owner goes to add layout updates that override module file updates.  This is How The System Works™ and changing it would create more chaos than it would solve.

That said, you might be able to work within the system if you put your code in a different layout handle.  Handles are the node that surround the layout updates

```
<default>
    ...   
</default>

<catalog_category_view>
</catalog_category_view>

<customer_logged_out>
</customer_logged_out>

etc...
```

The way Magento's layout system works is:

- all the updates in the `default` tag are run from module files, and then from `local.xml`.
- Then all the updates from `catalog_category_view` are run from module files, and then from `local.xml`.
- Then all the updates from `customer_logged_out` are run from module files, and then from `local.xml`.

That is, there's a handle order/specificity.  Checkout the Layout tab of [the Commerce Bug Demo store](http://commercebugdemo.pulsestorm.net/electronics/cell-phones.html) (after clicking debug) to see the handle order for a page. (disclaimer: Commerce Bug is a product I created and sell)

So, if your `local.xml` file applied its updates in `default` and you really can't rejigger this, then you could apply your module updates in a handle that came later.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Alan! The first update is run in default handle, is there another handle that is ran after that is applied on every page view?

Comment: @Vindfrisk There is no single handle other than `default` which is used everywhere.  But there is always one of `customer_logged_in` or `customer_logged_out` so if you copy your XML to both of those it will override `default`.

Comment: @clockworkgeek, Nope, I just tried it, and `default` is not getting overwritten by `customer_logged_out` or `customer_logged_in`. I tried it in Magento 1.9

Answer (score 2):

Your local.xml layout file will have precedence over all the other xml files (except for the /app/etc/local.xml file, but you should not be using that for layout).

You should remove the declaration from the local.xml file.